# If then statements in mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I was wondering if there was a way to conditionally return state values in mapStateToProps given prop information. See below for some sample code. I am getting some unexpected parsing errors. Is there a way to do something like this? Thanks.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => (
  if (ownProps.name === "alpha") {
    return {
      data: state.alpha.data
    }
  } else if (ownProps.name === "beta") {
    return {
      data: state.beta.data    
    }
  } else {
    return null;
  }
);
```

Comment: Curly braces for block scope...

Comment: It's most likely just `(` instead of `{` as your function body it complains about. `const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => { ... };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using the selector pattern instead of inserting logic directly.

```
selectorName(state, name) {
    if (name === 'alpha') return state.alpha.data
    else if (name === 'beta') return state.beta.data
    else return null
}
```

Then in mapStateToProps:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return { data: selectorName(state, ownProps.name) }
}
```

It helps to reduce potential mistakes and also makes unit testing easier. As an added bonus the data prop will not be null instead of the entire props.

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of JavaScript's [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) like this:

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  switch (ownProps.name) {
    case "alpha":
      return {
        data: state.alpha.data
      };
    case "beta":
      return {
        data: state.beta.data
      };
    default:
      return null; 
  }
};
```

NOTE: The issue with your code is that you are using **`(`** instead of **`{`** in the `block scope` of the functions' body.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, you just need to write it as a normal function with curly braces instead of parentheses for an immediate return expression.